# convergence of function of Brownian motion

Tags: statistics, convergence-divergence, statistical-inference

Teachers:

I have come across the following problem:

Suppose we have time series of $B_{i\Delta}$ with $i=0,1\ldots,n-1$ and $B_{t}$ is a standard Brownian motion.

How to prove the following results: (as $\Delta\to 0$, $n\to\infty$ and $n\Delta\to\infty$)
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{B_{\left(n-1\right)\Delta}\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n-1}
B_{l\Delta}}{\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n-1}\left(B_{l\Delta}\right)^{2}} &\overset{p}{\rightarrow}&0\,,\\
\frac{\left(B_{\left(n-1\right)\Delta}\right)^{2}}{2\Delta
\sum\limits_{l=0}^{n-1}\left(B_{l\Delta}\right)^{2}}&\overset{L}{\rightarrow}&\frac{\int_{0}^{1}BdB}{\int_{0}^{1}B^{2}dr}\,,
\end{eqnarray}
where $\overset{p}{\rightarrow}$ means convergence in probability and $\overset{L}{\rightarrow}$ means convergence in distribution.

Appricating for your kindly help.

Comment: What is $H$...?

Comment: Sorry for typo. Now the question is clear. Thanks for you hep.